# Old woman who sew a cloth with lot of hardwork and then tears it apart: where it is mentioned in Quran?

Tags: quran, source-identification, verses

I remember Quran says, don't be like an old woman who sew a cloth with lot of hard work but something comes in her mind and she tears it apart

Where this thing is mentioned in Quran, I am unable to find a chapter and verse number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are referring to the following Verse in Surat an-Nahl

> Do not behave like that woman who had spun yarn laboriously and then
>   had herself broken it into pieces.90 You make your mutual oaths a
>   means of mutual deceit in your affairs so that one people might take
>   undue advantage over the other whereas Allah puts you to trial by
>   these pledges.Allah will certainly reveal to you the truth about all
>   your differences on the Day of Resurrection
>
> [16:92]
>
> ولا تكونوا كالتي نقضت غزلها من بعد قوة أنكاثا تتخذون أيمانكم دخلا
>   بينكم أن تكون أمة هي أربى من أمة إنما يبلوكم الله به وليبينن لكم يوم
>   القيامة ما كنتم فيه تختلفون